# Mocking URLSeachParams

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

We are using `jest` for mocking. `enzyme` for rendering in our application.

Here I am trying to mock `URLSearchParams`'s `get` method.

I tried to use

```
jest.spyOn(URLSearchParams, 'get');
```

But it's not working.

My react class looks like bellow

```
export default class Concepts extends React.Component {
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(props.search);
  return {
     keyword: searchParams.get('q')
   };
}
```

My test is looks like below

```
it('should be able to change the state', () => {
  jest.spyOn(URLSearchParams, 'get');
  const wrapper = mount(
        <Concepts search="test" />
   );
});
```

Is it correct way? are there any other ways to do it? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 18):

You have to mock `get` on `URLSearchParams.prototype`, like :

```
jest.spyOn(URLSearchParams.prototype, 'get').mockImplementation((key) => key);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this!

```
jest.spyOn(URLSearchParams.prototype, "get").mockReturnValue("some value");
```

Answer (score 5):

This is my solution to mock [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```
global.URLSearchParams = jest.fn(x => ({
  get: jest.fn(y => x.includes(y) ? 'url does contain get parameter' : 'url does not contain get parameter'),
}));
```

Comment: This worked best for me because it can easily be modified at the start of each individual test.